# Is there something like Rust's core::hint::spin_loop for C++?

Tags: c++, spinlock

I'm implementing a spin lock in C++ (since for whatever reason there's no spin lock implementation in the standard library) and I'm looking for a cross-platform and cross-architecture way to emit a PAUSE/YIELD instruction.
Rust has [`core::hint::spin_loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/hint/fn.spin_loop.html) for that. Is there something similar for C++?

Comment: you can probably peek into e.g. boost library internals: [spinlock](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_std_atomic.hpp),  [yield](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp) and so on.

Comment: Have a look at Google's absl, Facebook's folly, they are production level libraries that have spinlock and other similar but more powful utils.

Comment: @dewaffled [the boost implementation of `sp_thread_pause`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_thread_pause.hpp) unfortunately only has an x86 implementation.

Comment: @eyelash What implementation do you need? Rust [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/hint.rs.html#110-140) only x86(-64) and ARM(64).

Comment: @DanielKleinstein at least x86 and ARM but preferably something future-proof that I don't need to manually update in the future in order to support more architectures.

Comment: it seems folly indeed has more architectures covered in [asm_volatile_pause](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/portability/Asm.h#L36)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like

> std::this_thread::yield();

?

Comment: this gives the wrong behaviour as it operates at the OS level telling it to reschedule the thread. the spinlock hint in rust on the other hand is a hint to the compiler to emit processor level code to e.g. switch to power saving mode